# Textbox placeholder

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have MVC project and Im using Viewbag for filter using textbox.

All I want is placeholder in the textbox like "Search by name". I found alot of options how to do it but not a single one when you are using viewbag.

It might be stupid question but Im kinda new to programing so any kind of help is appreciated.

```c#
Search: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to the solution. The `Html.TextBox()` has some overloads. One of the parameter is a dictionary with that you can add attributes to the generated html element:

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new {placeholder = "your placeholder goes here" })
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but what If I want it to be grey ?

Comment: If you want it to be grey use like this    @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new {placeholder = "your placeholder goes here", @style="color:grey" })

Comment: If my comment is useful to u please mark it as useful

Comment: I would like to, but since I just registred I can not :) anyway, thanks for help.